# Object sets with for of loops for quiz

Tags: javascript, object, set

Instructions:

```
* Programming Quiz: Using Sets (3-1)
*
* Create a Set object and store it in a variable named `myFavoriteFlavors`. 
Add the following strings to the set:
*     - chocolate chip
*     - cookies and cream
*     - strawberry
*     - vanilla
*
* Then use the `.delete()` method to remove "strawberry" from the set.
*/
```

My code

```
const MyFavoriteFlavors = new MyFavoriteFlavors();
for (const MyFavoriteFlavors1 of MyFavoriteFlavors)
 MyFavoriteFlavors.add('chocolate chip');
 MyFavoriteFlavors.add('cookies and cream'); 
 MyFavoriteFlavors.add('strawberry'); 
 MyFavoriteFlavors.add('vanilla');
MyFavoriteFlavors.delete('strawberry');
console.log(MyFavoriteFlavors);
```

Can someone help me fix my code so it fits with in the instructions?
Also tell me what I can focus on to improve my code since I have been working on this quiz for two days solid.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a Set object to start with, somewhere in your code, since currently you don't have one anywhere:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```
const MyFavoriteFlavors = new Set();
```

Comment: I think that was what I was trying to do with the first line. Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: It works lol Wow that hurt my brain thanks so much @CertainPerformance!

Comment: I still need to clean up some of it. But you got me on the right track.